# Can some one tell me how do i do this SQL column to row

Tags: sql

my table data is like this

```
id Q1 Q2 Q3
1  4  3  2
```

what i want is a query which can display data in this format

```
id Answers
1  4
1  3 
1  2
```

and there is one more table that has the same id , i want to show columns from that table too so its a join to want to show data like above.

Comment: Which RDMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

A `union all` does this:

```
select id, q1 as answer from t union all
select id, q2 as answer from t union all
select id, q3 as answer from t 
order by id;
```

Comment: i dont have one row in my table they are more. i cant write this query for 500 rows it will be like 500* 3 queries.

Comment: @MehboobSamnani you don't have to. Just type it once as above

Comment: @Gordon - I made an edit to include an "order by id." Thought this would make sense to view the output by id instead by showing all the q1 answers, then all the q2 answers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**IF SQL Server**, you can go a little more dynamic.

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,Q1 int, Q2 int, Q3 int)
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,4,3,2),
(2,6,4,7)


Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @YourTable for XML RAW)

Select ID    = r.value('@id','int')
      ,Item  = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="id"]') as B(attr)
```

Returns

```
ID  Item    Value
1   Q1      4
1   Q2      3
1   Q3      2
2   Q1      6
2   Q2      4
2   Q3      7
```